# Using PHP to generate SVG with unicode characters to be included in Inkscape

Tags: php, svg, encoding, utf-8, inkscape

I have to make some PDF calendars, so I decided to automate the process creating the bulk of the days in SVG with PHP, saving the result and importing it in Inkscape for further graphics.

Generally this procedure works smoothly, and I've used it many times for graphs, diagrams, etc., but now I've an issue with utf-8 characters, which I never had to use before.

This is the basic PHP code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="1200" height="3600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" encoding="UTF-8">

<?php
$FontSize = 16;
$LineHeight = $FontSize * 1.5;
$DefaultColor = '000000';
$Y = $LineHeight;

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome');
setlocale(LC_TIME, "it_IT.utf8");

for ($mese=1; $mese<=12; $mese++) {
    $M = strftime('%B', strtotime("$mese/1/2016"));
    echo "<g id=\"$M\">\n";
    echo "<text x=\"0\" y=\"$Y\" style=\"font-size:{$FontSize}px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0\">$M</text>\n";
    $Y = $Y + $LineHeight;
    for ($giorno=1; $giorno<=cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $mese, 2016); $giorno++) {
        $G =utf8_decode(strftime('%A', strtotime("$mese/$giorno/2016")));
        $D = strftime('%e', strtotime("$mese/$giorno/2016"));
        if (strftime('%u', strtotime("$mese/$giorno/2016"))==7) {
            $colore = 'ff0000';
        } else {
            $colore = $DefaultColor;
        }
        echo "<text x=\"10\" y=\"$Y\" style=\"font-size:{$FontSize}px;fill:#{$colore};fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0\">$D</text>\n";
        echo "<text x=\"40\" y=\"$Y\" style=\"font-size:{$FontSize}px;fill:#{$colore};fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0\">$G</text>\n";
        $Y = $Y + $LineHeight;
    }
    $Y = $Y + $LineHeight;
    echo "</g>\n";
}
?>
</svg>
```

The SVG output is (snippet):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">

<svg width="1200" height="3600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" encoding="UTF-8">

<g id="gennaio">
<text x="0" y="24" style="font-size:16px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0">gennaio</text>
<text x="10" y="48" style="font-size:16px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0"> 1</text>
<text x="40" y="48" style="font-size:16px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0">venerdì</text>
<text x="10" y="72" style="font-size:16px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0"> 2</text>
<text x="40" y="72" style="font-size:16px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0">sabato</text>
<text x="10" y="96" style="font-size:16px;fill:#ff0000;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0"> 3</text>
<text x="40" y="96" style="font-size:16px;fill:#ff0000;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0">domenica</text>
<text x="10" y="120" style="font-size:16px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0"> 4</text>
<text x="40" y="120" style="font-size:16px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0">lunedì</text>
```

On the screen it works smoothly.

However, when with Firefox I save the generated page, the utf-8 encoding is lost, and Inkscape can't deal with this. Every final "ì" of the Italian day names is replaced with a long line of undefined characters.

When I check the "page informations" from Firefox I see the encoding is "Windows-1252", and I don't know where it comes from, while if I save the resulting page and open it with the text editor Kate I see the encoding is ISO-8859-15, and the "ì" are correctly shown in the file.

If I check the saved file from console (`less file.svg`, with `XTERM_LOCALE=it_IT.utf8`) I see the "ì" are replaced with inverted `<EC>` hexcodes. U+00EC is "LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH GRAVE", so at least it is correct.

If I re-save the page from Kate, forcing the encoding to UTF-8, Inkscape gladly accepts it.

If I try to replace the "ì" with the html entity `&igrave;` Inkscape doesn't show the glyph.

The question is: **how can I save the page seen on Firefox as UTF-8?** It seems Firefox doesn't allow to change the encoding of the files, as Kate does.

Comment: Can't you write the character in an empty Inkscape document, save it and see how it has written it away to the SVG file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use PHP to prep SVG file for use in img tag data uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41171623/use-php-to-prep-svg-file-for-use-in-img-tag-data-uri)