# Use PHP to prep SVG file for use in img tag data uri

Tags: php, html, image, svg

I'm using PHP. I would like to use file_get_contents to get an .svg file, and convert it for use as a data uri in an image tag. Something along these lines:

Controller:

```
$mylogo   = file_get_contents(FCPATH.'app/views/emails/images/mylogo.svg');
```

View:

```
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<?= $mylogo ?>">
```

I need to convert it into something (base64?) as right now it is just dumping it in tags and all and though the image does appear, it makes a mess of the img tag surrounding it.

Comment: As far as I'm aware - and I could be wrong here - an SVG doesn't need to be the source of an image tag. The SVG element can be echoed directly onto the page.

Comment: Nice - I was sure you needed it to be in an image tag to embed it, but that worked perfectly. If you want to make it an answer, I'll happily accept it.

Comment: This also worked for me, but was unneccesary as you pointed out: `$mylogo   = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,'.base64_encode(file_get_contents(FCPATH.'app/views/emails/images/mylogo.svg'));`

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working - I did post an answer for you that expands a bit more :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<svg>` elements can be echoed directly onto a web page like any other element; there's no need to include it as an `img` `src` attribute. PHP's `include` can be used for this (ie. `include('/path/to/image.svg')`), amongst a myriad of other methods.

Alternatively, if for some reason you *need* to include the `svg` as an actual `img` tag, there's no need for `file_get_contents` or similar functions; an SVG can be linked as a source path like any other image type (ie. `<image src="/path/to/image.svg">`).

Comment: Thanks for this, that's great. I didn't think they could just be a part of the dom, so this is great. For the second part of your answer I was definitely aware of that method - my purpose though was to embed the svg into an email so there wouldn't be any attachments or dependencies to retrieve.

Answer (score 4):

## Solution

### Controller

```
$encodedSVG = \rawurlencode(\str_replace(["\r", "\n"], ' ', \file_get_contents($path)));
```

### View

```
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<?= $encodedSVG ?>">
```

---

## ⚠️ Do not convert to base64

It's less efficient in CPU time and also makes longer requests in size!

[Know more about why](https://css-tricks.com/probably-dont-base64-svg/)